# Is there a better way to coerce an integer to a floating point in Ruby besides .round(1)?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, integer, coercion

Just what the question says in the title. I have a pair of integers, I want to convert it to a floating point so that I can do floating point math on it (to get a nice percentage).

Right now my code looks like this.

```
(failure_and_run_count[:failure].round(1) / failure_and_run_count[:run].round(1)) * 100.0
```

Someone please tell me there is a nicer way to coerce the ints inside of failure_and_run_count to floating points.

Comment: take a look here http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Number_Classes_and_Conversions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the method `to_f` for the purpose:

```
1.to_f # => 1.0
1.to_f.class # => Float
```

In your example:

```
failure_and_run_count[:failure] / failure_and_run_count[:run].to_f * 100.0
```

Only one operand needs to be explicitly coerced to `Float` since the other is automatically coerced when you call the `/` method.

Pay attention because nasty things could happen:

```
''.to_f # => 0.0
nil.to_f # => 0.0
'foo'.to_f # => 0.0
```

Comment: So I was looking at the Integer class (http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html) assuming that the to_f function would live there. Why do I need to look at Fixnum instead of Integer?

Comment: @Jazzepi `Integer` is the (abstract) base class for both `Fixnum` (integers that fits a machine word) and `Bignum` (integer bigger then `Fixnum`s), the `to_f` method is defined in the subclasses. More info on Ruby numeric types [here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/numbers_in_ruby.html).

Comment: Thanks! That's a great answer. LAST QUESTION I PROMISE :) Is there any way to tell that Integer is the abstract class? I come from a Java background and I'm used to stuff like that being marked abstract. I realize now at the top of the Integer document it mentions that this class is an abstract class, but is there anything /other/ than that text that I should, or can, look for?

Comment: In Ruby abstract classes are not explicitly marked as such. It's quite impossible to explain how them can be implemented in a comment, especially to someone with a Java background! :-) Here on SO you can find lot of great explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Two possible options:

The **Float** method takes its argument and converts it to a floating-point number, terminating the program with an error if that conversion fails.

```
(failure_and_run_count[:failure] / Float(failure_and_run_count[:run])) * 100.0
```

**to_f**: Converts the number to a Float. If the number doesn’t fit in a Float, the result is infinity.

```
(failure_and_run_count[:failure] / failure_and_run_count[:run].to_f) * 100.0
```

Comment: `Infinity` could be returned in both cases: `Float(1000**1000) # => Infinity`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Float (failure_and_run_count[:failure])
```